# Command line editing and text editor on AIX

Tags: command-line, ksh, aix, editors

Recently my company is moving an application system from mainframe z/OS to AIX.  I have some experience on Ubuntu, but am completely new to AIX 6.1.
Just wondering a few question:

1. We use putty to connect to the AIX servers, but putty is very difficult to operate.  You cannot use up arrow to recall the command in history.  Is there any better terminal that is more user friendly in AIX?
2. AIX is using ksh, instead of Bash.  Is there any login shell with a special name that every time you login it can execute automatically, just like the `.bashrc` in ubuntu?
3. There's no gedit nor nano nor vim on my AIX, only vi.  Is there any text editor that I can download/use without root permission?

Comment: I found the answer for Q2.  It's `.profile`. Though someone says it should be .kshrc or .ksrc, as per my test, on my AIX, it's .profile only.

Comment: /usr/bin/ksh93 should support .kshrc

Comment: you're right.  I did find ksh93.

Comment: All shells (bash included) should support `.profile`

Answer (score 9):

The default login shell for AIX is not bash - it is ksh/posix. The reason why the "up" arrow isn't working is because KSH is set to "vi" mode (bash can do this too). You want "emacs" mode:

```
set -o emacs
```

The .bashrc equivalent is .profile. You can put the above in there to change it permanently. AIX actually gives you two versions of KSH - ksh88 (default) and ksh93. The latter supports .kshrc as well

You can also install bash (and vim, nano etc) on AIX using an RPM available from one of the publicly available repositories.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that AIX uses ksh88 by default (+1).  Which, well, is quite old. On  the other hand i believe that the arrows should still work inside `set -o vi`.  The arrows are more [at its loss with ksh itselff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-kornshell-command-line).  And I'm confident that PuTTY has a workaround in its config pane, although i had not used that for 10 years.

Comment: thanks.  `set -o emacs` works and made my life easier.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that all three questions are answered by going to the [IBM toolbox](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html) and installing `yum`.  From there you have the range of the RPMs provided by IBM (compiled open source packages), or, moreover from [perlz](http://www.perzl.org/aix/) which offers a much bigger range.  Note that *perlz* is a project completely unrelated to IBM.

Also, to install the `yum` RPM you need `yum`.  But people figured out that that is not very user friendly so the [yum readme](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/README-yum) explains two methods to install `yum`.  Either you can install all RPMs by hand (it lists all of them) or download a full bundle and install them.

And the questions:

> We use putty to connect to the AIX servers, but putty is very difficult to operate. You cannot use up arrow to recall the command in history. Is there any better terminal that is more user friendly in AIX?

You can PuTTY has a configuration parameter that switches between different types of arrow coding.  If I'm not mistaken (haven't used PuTTY for a long time) the default is "Linux" which is escaping with `<ESC>[[`.  If I remember correctly I needed to change that config to use PuTTY to connect directly to an AIX box.

> AIX is using ksh, instead of Bash. Is there any login shell with a special name that every time you login it can execute automatically, just like the .bashrc in ubuntu?

`bash` does use `.profile` too, for login shells.  When connecting through PuTTY you are using a login shell.  Therefore installing (and using) `bash` (through *perlz*, see above) instead of `ksh` is an option.  `ksh` is POSIX compliant but lacks several features that people are used to on `bash`.

> There's no gedit nor nano nor vim on my AIX, only vi. Is there any text editor that I can download/use without root permission?

Again *perlz*, there is a `nano` package and a `vim` package.

#### Extra considerations (disclaimer)

If you are using the AIX machine in production and realy on IBM for maintenance, the use of `perlz* packages may be a violation of contract with IBM.  Do check that, IBM is not famous for being lenient on contract clauses.

One way to get around the problem (at least how we got around it where I worked with AIX) was to install *perlz* packages on development servers but not on production servers.  And we needed to take care of the development servers ourselves.  In such a case (and if you install `bash`) remember to use `#!/bin/ksh` and not `#!/bin/sh` in scripts to prevent surprises in production.

Also, AIX 6.1 is quite old.  I remember using it in 2009.  The current version is 7.2, if you are switching servers to new ones I see no reason to use the old version.

Comment: Or don't change the system's default shell. Just set your personal login shell to bash.

Comment: @OrangeDog - heh, yeah, fully agree,  But you never know what another developer will do when working as a team.  And better be safe.  And, yes, it did happen to me to run a script with the wrong shell because someone else changed it :)

Comment: Don't give them `root` access if you can't trust them not to change the system shell.

Comment: I am not the AIX operation system admin.  I am just a supporter for an application system.  As I don't have the root permission, I don't have to worry about changing the system default shell.  Just out of curiosity, in scripts, the first shebang line should always specify which shell to use, why it can still cause 'run a script with the wrong shell' issue?

Comment: @0PT1MU5PR1ME - Someone may think that it would be good to have `bash` as the default for new users and (instead of changing the skeleton) symlink `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`.  The you test the script and all works.  But, on a new (or production, or client, machine) `/bin/sh` would be symlinked to `/bin/ksh` as the is the default that IBM sets on new machines.

Comment: We don't have yum.  I think sys admins use lslpp.  Is it possible to download the source code from the 'IBM toolbox' mentioned above and install them manually without root?

Comment: @0PT1MU5PR1ME - [Of course it is!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787375/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-an-rpm)  An RPM is simply an archive from which you can extract the files from (that question oulines `rpm2cpio` and then `cpio`).  AIX should come with an `rpm` command, but even if it doesn't you can extract the files on a different machine (e.g. RedHat, Fedora) and copy them over.  Just, if you are doing things that way **document it**, people will appreciate that you document what hacks are needed to keep a machine running.